# LinkedList operator>> overloading error (undefined reference)

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I have a `LinkedList` object, I'm trying to have an overloaded `operator>>` which takes a `LinkedList`, asks the user for an input and then breaks it into words and creates a new node for every word. But I'm not exactly sure why I cant use `cin >> *inputOne`.

In the code below `value_type` is a string and `l.add(subs)` is adding the string into the `LinkedList`:

From main:

```
LinkedList* inputOne = new LinkedList();
cin >> *inputOne; //i get an error here
```

From LinkedList.cpp:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& ins, LinkedList& l)
{
    value_type i = "";

    cin >> i;

    istringstream iss(i);

    value_type subs;

    while(iss >> subs)
    {
        l.add(subs);
    }

    return ins;
}
```

So far I'm getting this error:

> ```
> main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, LinkedList const&)'
> main.cpp:21:(.text+0x59): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `operator>>(std::istream&, LinkedList const&)'
> ```

Comment: Take a look at the error message, and look at your declaration of the `operator>>` function. It's not the same is it? Are you perhaps doing input somewhere else? Using a `const` object?

Comment: And what is `value_type`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: Lastly, is there a specific reason to use pointers and `new` for the list object? If you can avoid pointers then do it, and if you can't then use smart pointers (like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)).

Comment: What line corresponds to `main.cpp:21` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's for an assignment, so I have to use pointers. value_type is just a typedef for a string.

Comment: I understand that the nodes have to be pointers, but the list object itself?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah unfortunately, I lose marks if it isn't. Your first suggestion worked by the way, thank you.